# .Net Core hosted angular app returns 404 for all API calls

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, http-status-code-404, .net-core

I had problem with Angular 4.0 app with .Net Core backend. I develop application using `npm start` which contains this call `"concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress --port 8080\" \"dotnet run\"` " When I was developing there wasn't any problem but when I test to run only `dotnet run` problems started. I managed to navigate to my login page but when I tried to login all API calls return 404 Exception. I aldo tested other API calls than login and they also returned 404.

Comment: You probably should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to found the source of problem. So this is for those who are strugling with same kind of problem.

Cause of problem was my angular route config. There I have this line which take all not angular route calls and also all API calls and return user back to login page:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: "login", }
```

So all-in-all you should not use ** if you host your angular app with same service with your .Net Core web API.